# Smart Folder not picking up images in subfolders

Tags: macos, photos.app, photo-stream, smart-folders

Until recently I used [this excellent tip](http://theiconmaster.com/2012/04/the-easy-way-to-get-ios-screenshots-on-your-mac/), to create a (smart) folder on my mac showing all the screenshots that I have taken with my iPhone (via the iPhoto directory system and photostream). This was on Lion.

I'm now using a new harddrive with a fresh install of Mavericks on it, and when I try to repeat the tip I get nowhere.

I can see the directory structure in

```
/Users/josephreddington/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets/sub
```

as it was before, and it looks just like this:

[image]

So all the files are there, but when I put try and search for kind=png, I oddly get exactly one result:

[image]

rather than hundreds.  I get no results at all when searching for kind=jpg, and that should pick up all of the camera photos in the subfolders - what am I doing wrong?

(This also is the case if the search is saved and accessed later)

or even